# Find the maximum Domain of the following expression

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus

$$E(x)=\log(1+ \sqrt{\vert x \vert}-x)$$

I’ve tried so far to put the condition of existence of logarithm such that $(1+\sqrt{\vert x \vert}-x) \gt 0$ and I’ve come up with an interval $\left(\frac{3-\sqrt 5}{2}, \frac{3+\sqrt 5}{2}\right)$ how I should find other restrictions?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Are you asking about the function domain or range? By the way, be careful about your solution of $$1+\sqrt{|x|} -x>0,$$which is incorrect, if I correctly interpret what you wrote. Just check what happens with negative values of $x$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you observed, the only restriction is
$$1+\sqrt{|x|}-x>0,$$
that is
$$\sqrt{|x|}>x-1.\tag{1}\label{1}$$

If the RHS of \eqref{1} is negative, the inequality is satisfied. Thus \eqref{1} is equivalent to
$$ x<1 \ \lor \begin{cases}x-1\geq 0\\ |x|> (x-1)^2\end{cases},$$
leading to the domain
$$D = \left(-\infty; \frac{3+\sqrt 5}2\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that the interval $\left(\frac{3-\sqrt 5}{2}, \frac{3+\sqrt 5}{2}\right)$ is the solution to the inequality $1+\sqrt{\vert x \vert}-x \gt 0$ for $x\ge 1$. So, the valid interval is actually $\left(1, \frac{3+\sqrt 5}{2}\right)$. For $x<1$, the inequality holds regardless. Therefore, the domain is $x<\frac{3+\sqrt 5}{2}$.